# How can I combine data-toggle with data-tooltip?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, tooltip

Like this my data-toggle is working well:

```
<button data-toggle="control-sidebar" href="{{ path('forms', {slug:page.slug}) }}" class="edit-item btn btn-box-tool" data-id="'+ data +'" data-target="edit"><span class="fa fa-pen"></span></button>
```

But when I add a tooltip, the tooltip is working but the data-toggle is not working anymore:

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="edit" data-toggle="control-sidebar" href="{{ path('forms', {slug:page.slug}) }}" class="edit-item btn btn-box-tool" data-id="'+ data +'" data-target="edit"><span class="fa fa-pen"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple `data-toggle` in the same tag.

You need to separate them

```
<button data-toggle="control-sidebar" href="{{ path('forms', {slug:page.slug}) }}" class="edit-item btn btn-box-tool" data-id="'+ data +'" data-target="edit">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="edit" class="fa fa-pen"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: I tested this. Now the control-sidebar toggle is working again and also the link. But now I do not see the tooltip anymore

Comment: @Jarla you do have `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` right?

Comment: I found now a working solution: `<span href="{{ path('forms', {slug:page.slug}) }}" data-toggle="control-sidebar" class="edit-item" data-id="'+ data +'" data-target="edit"><a class="btn btn-box-tool" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="edit"><span class="fa fa-pen"></span></a></span>`

Comment: @Jarla putting a span outside works fine too, but inside should work as well, it's weird that it's not. Anyways i'm happy you found the answer!